# Removing object properties with Lodash

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have to remove unwanted object properties that do not match my model. How can I achieve it with Lodash?

My model is:

```
var model = {
   fname: null,
   lname: null
}
```

My controller output before sending to the server will be:

```
var credentials = {
    fname: "xyz",
    lname: "abc",
    age: 23
}
```

I am aware I can use

```
delete credentials.age
```

but what if I have lots of unwanted properties? Can I achieve it with Lodash?

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Get a list of properties from `model` using [`_.keys()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.16.4#keys), and use [`_.pick()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.16.4#pick) to extract the properties from `credentials` to a new object:

```js
var model = {
   fname:null,
   lname:null
};

var credentials = {
    fname:"xyz",
    lname:"abc",
    age:23
};

var result = _.pick(credentials, _.keys(model));

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.16.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

If you don't want to use Lodash, you can use [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys), and [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```js
var model = {
   fname:null,
   lname:null
};

var credentials = {
    fname:"xyz",
    lname:"abc",
    age:23
};

var result = Object.keys(model).reduce(function(obj, key) {
  obj[key] = credentials[key];
  return obj;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: how can we achieve the same if the object is nested, for ex
const obj = { a: {b: 1, c: 2}}, i want to remove only c, expected output should be.
{a: {b:1}}

Comment: One of the simple and neat answer

Answer (score 234):

You can approach it from either an "allow list" or a "block list" way:

```js
// Block list
// Remove the values you don't want
var result = _.omit(credentials, ['age']);

// Allow list
// Only allow certain values
var result = _.pick(credentials, ['fname', 'lname']);
```

If it's reusable business logic, you can partial it out as well:

```js
// Partial out a "block list" version
var clean = _.partial(_.omit, _, ['age']);

// and later
var result = clean(credentials);
```

### Note that Lodash 5 will drop support for omit

A similar approach can be achieved without Lodash:

```js
const transform = (obj, predicate) => {
    return Object.keys(obj).reduce((memo, key) => {
    if(predicate(obj[key], key)) {
        memo[key] = obj[key]
    }
    return memo
    }, {})
}

const omit = (obj, items) => transform(obj, (value, key) => !items.includes(key))

const pick = (obj, items) => transform(obj, (value, key) => items.includes(key))

// Partials
// Lazy clean
const cleanL = (obj) => omit(obj, ['age'])

// Guarded clean
const cleanG = (obj) => pick(obj, ['fname', 'lname'])


// "App"
const credentials = {
    fname:"xyz",
    lname:"abc",
    age:23
}

const omitted = omit(credentials, ['age'])
const picked = pick(credentials, ['age'])
const cleanedL = cleanL(credentials)
const cleanedG = cleanG(credentials)
```

Comment: this is the correct answer since the function that removes is `_.omit` while `_.pick` specifies which you want (which is quite the opposite)

Comment: correct - and depends on your general approach and surrounding business logic - either version will work depending on your requirements

Comment: For the partial you made a typo, its `_.partial(_.omit ...`.

Comment: The blacklist IS the answer expected for this question. Should be the right answer

Comment: **WARNING:** - [omit is slated to be removed in version 5](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/wiki/Roadmap) (see the [discussion here](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/issues/2930))

Comment: Very interesting. I will update the answer to mark it for lodash4, then revisit once lodash5 is officially released

Comment: Thanks @cale_b I've reworked the answer to include a version with lodash _omitted_

Comment: @Chris - sorry for the confusion - they recommend `_.pick` over `_.omit`, with some decent reasoning... so I was just suggesting using pick would be preferred for future compatibility... :)

Comment: @cale_b Thanks, you explained it perfectly. I figured because I would have to write something to replace omit I might as well show an example of doing it without Lodash altogether. I love Lodash but if omit is being removed, might as well go with a lighter alternative of omit

Comment: If anyone is interested in the edits to this question please see: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/350880/what-is-stack-exchanges-official-stance-on-words-such-as-black-list-white-l

Comment: Someone knows why they're going to remove `_.omit`? `_.omit` and `_.pick` serve different purposes...

Answer (score 9):

You can easily do this using _.pick:

```js
var model = {
  fname: null,
  lname: null
};

var credentials = {
  fname: 'abc',
  lname: 'xyz',
  age: 2
};

var result = _.pick(credentials, _.keys(model));


console.log('result =', result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/lodash/4.16.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

But you can simply use pure JavaScript (specially if you use [ECMAScript 6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript#6th_Edition_-_ECMAScript_2015)), like this:

```js
const model = {
  fname: null,
  lname: null
};

const credentials = {
  fname: 'abc',
  lname: 'xyz',
  age: 2
};

const newModel = {};

Object.keys(model).forEach(key => newModel[key] = credentials[key]);

console.log('newModel =', newModel);
```

Answer (score 8):

Lodash `unset` is suitable for removing a few unwanted keys.

```js
const myObj = {
    keyOne: "hello",
    keyTwo: "world"
}

unset(myObj, "keyTwo");

console.log(myObj); /// myObj = { keyOne: "hello" }
```

Answer (score 4):

Here I have used *omit()* for the respective 'key' which you want to remove... by using the Lodash library:

```
var credentials = [{
        fname: "xyz",
        lname: "abc",
        age: 23
}]

let result = _.map(credentials, object => {
                       return _.omit(object, ['fname', 'lname'])
                   })

console.log('result', result)
```

Comment: be careful when you want to use `omit`, I used to like `omit` before but now it got `removed` : https://github.com/lodash/lodash/issues/2930

Answer (score 1):

You can use `_.omit()` for emitting the key from a JSON array if you have fewer objects:

```
_.forEach(data, (d) => {
    _.omit(d, ['keyToEmit1', 'keyToEmit2'])
});
```

If you have more objects, you can use the reverse of it which is `_.pick()`:

```
_.forEach(data, (d) => {
    _.pick(d, ['keyToPick1', 'keyToPick2'])
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To select (or remove) object properties that satisfy a given condition **deeply**, you can use something like this:

```js
function pickByDeep(object, condition, arraysToo=false) {
  return _.transform(object, (acc, val, key) => {
    if (_.isPlainObject(val) || arraysToo && _.isArray(val)) {
      acc[key] = pickByDeep(val, condition, arraysToo);
    } else if (condition(val, key, object)) {
      acc[key] = val;
    }
  });
}
```

https://codepen.io/aercolino/pen/MWgjyjm

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution to deep remove empty properties with Lodash:

```
const compactDeep = obj => {
    const emptyFields = [];

    function calculateEmpty(prefix, source) {
        _.each(source, (val, key) => {
           if (_.isObject(val) && !_.isEmpty(val)) {
                calculateEmpty(`${prefix}${key}.`, val);
            } else if ((!_.isBoolean(val) && !_.isNumber(val) && !val) || (_.isObject(val) && _.isEmpty(val))) {
                emptyFields.push(`${prefix}${key}`);
            }
        });
    }

    calculateEmpty('', obj);

    return _.omit(obj, emptyFields);
};
```

Comment: What is the idea? What does your solution do?

Comment: -1; this isn't useful for solving the example problem the asker gave, nor for the generic problem of removing properties from an object; it's a solution to a weirdly arbitrary problem that isn't the one asked and that isn't spelt out in this answer. It's also not idempotent (`compactDeep({a: {b: []}})` gives a different result to `compactDeep(compactDeep({a: {b: []}}))`, which feels like a bug, though one can't really say so objectively since it's not spelt out what this is meant to do.

Answer (score 0):

For array of objects

```
model = _.filter(model, a => {
          if (!a.age) { return a }
        })
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, and thank you for contributing an answer. Would you kindly edit your answer to to include an explanation of your code? That will help future readers better understand what is going on, and especially those members of the community who are new to the language and struggling to understand the concepts. That's especially important when there's already an answer from five years ago that's been validated by the community with 178 upvotes to date. Under what conditions might your approach be preferred? Are you taking advantage of new capabilities?

Answer (score 0):

**Recursively removing paths.**

I just needed something similar, not removing just keys, but keys by with paths recursively.

Thought I'd share.

**Simple readable example, no dependencies**

```js
/**
 * Removes path from an object recursively.
 * A full path to the key is not required.
 * The original object is not modified.
 *
 * Example:
 *   const original = { a: { b: { c: 'value' } }, c: 'value'  }
 *
 *   omitPathRecursively(original, 'a') // outputs: { c: 'value' }
 *   omitPathRecursively(original, 'c') // outputs: { a: { b: {} } }
 *   omitPathRecursively(original, 'b.c') // { a: { b: {} }, c: 'value' }
 */
export const omitPathRecursively = (original, path, depth = 1) => {
  const segments = path.split('.')
  const final = depth === segments.length

  return JSON.parse(
    JSON.stringify(original, (key, value) => {
      const match = key === segments[depth - 1]

      if (!match) return value
      if (!final) return omitPathRecursively(value, path, depth + 1)
      return undefined
    })
  )
}
```

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/webbertakken/60thvguc/1/

Answer (score 0):

While looking for a solution that would work for both arrays and objects, I didn't find one and so I created it.

```js
/**
 * Recursively ignore keys from array or object
 */
const ignoreKeysRecursively = (obj, keys = []) => {
  const keyIsToIgnore = (key) => {
    return keys.map((a) => a.toLowerCase()).includes(key)
  }

  const serializeObject = (item) => {
    return Object.fromEntries(
      Object.entries(item)
        .filter(([key, value]) => key && value)
        .reduce((prev, curr, currIndex) => {
          if (!keyIsToIgnore(curr[0]))
            prev[currIndex] =
              [
                curr[0],
                // serialize array
                Array.isArray(curr[1])
                  ? // eslint-disable-next-line
                  serializeArray(curr[1])
                  : // serialize object
                  !Array.isArray(curr[1]) && typeof curr[1] === 'object'
                  ? serializeObject(curr[1])
                  : curr[1],
              ] || []
          return prev
        }, []),
    )
  }

  const serializeArray = (item) => {
    const serialized = []
    for (const entry of item) {
      if (typeof entry === 'string') serialized.push(entry)
      if (typeof entry === 'object' && !Array.isArray(entry)) serialized.push(serializeObject(entry))
      if (Array.isArray(entry)) serialized.push(serializeArray(entry))
    }
    return serialized
  }

  if (Array.isArray(obj)) return serializeArray(obj)
  return serializeObject(obj)
}

// usage
const refObject = [{name: "Jessica", password: "ygd6g46"}]
// ignore password
const obj = ignoreKeysRecursively(refObject, ["password"])
// expects returned array to only have name attribute
console.log(obj)
```

Answer (score 0):

let asdf = [{"asd": 12, "asdf": 123}, {"asd": 121, "asdf": 1231}, {"asd": 142, "asdf": 1243}]

asdf = _.map(asdf, function (row) {
return _.omit(row, ['asd'])
})