# Remove Sub Element Using lodash

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have an array that looks like this.

```
0: {source: 'source0', value: 'value0', path: 'path0'}
1: {source: 'source1', value: 'value1', path: 'path1'}
2: {source: 'source2', value: 'value2', path: 'path2'}
```

I'd like to use lodash to return the array without the path element but can't seem to get it figured out.  TIA.

Comment: Have you had a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40329742/removing-object-properties-with-lodash ?

Comment: You could use destructuring: `sources.map( ({ path, ...rest}) => rest)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the delete operator in Vanilla JS

```
const objArr = [
    {source: 'source0', value: 'value0', path: 'path0'},
    {source: 'source1', value: 'value1', path: 'path1'},
    {source: 'source2', value: 'value2', path: 'path2'},
]

objArr.forEach(obj=>{
    delete obj.path
})

console.log(objArr)
/* Now it looks like this:
[
  { source: 'source0', value: 'value0' },
  { source: 'source1', value: 'value1' },
  { source: 'source2', value: 'value2' }
]
*/
```